# External hard drive unplugged while running iTunes...Corrupted files

Tags: itunes, hard-drive, external-disk, data-recovery

I have nearly 2TB of Movies and TV Shows copied to iTunes on an external hard drive. Last night, I was unplugging a cord behind my desk and I accidentally unplugged my HD. Well, when I plugged it back in and tried to open iTunes, it said that it was corrupted.

I couldn't figure out a work around for this so I made a new iTunes Library and pointed it to my media. I still couldn't get it to recognize my movies etc. This morning I tried to manually open one of the movies with Quicktime player and it says that it is not a movie file. HELP!!! This was days and days of work to transfer my DVD collection over.

Comment: @EmmEff If I could down vote that comment, I would. Of course I know that it should exist in two places. I just barely finished copying my movies and tv shows over and purchased an additional drive as a backup. I was planning to back up everything.

Comment: Sorry for pointing out the obvious. I removed the comment.

Comment: @zwerdlds I tried Disk Utility and Disk Warrior. Neither made any difference. I trie copying one of the files to another drive but it still won't open.

Answer (score 1):

The first recommendation is to run [Disk Utility](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1782) to repair the external drive. If it is a simple corruption Disk Utility can occasionally fix it.

The next step from that would be to run a higher-end data tree repair utility, such as [Disk Warrior](http://www.alsoft.com/diskwarrior/). This software costs a bit of money but is better at repairing serious directory structure issues such as this.

You could also attempt a software-based data recovery using a program like [Data Rescue](http://www.prosofteng.com/products/data_rescue.php). This software is just a bit pricey though, and at some point you will want to consider how valuable this data is. For instance, if it's a simple matter of re-downloading purchased movies or re-ripping DVDs it may be worth saving the money.

Comment: I used Disk Utility without success. I have and used Disk Warrior as well. The more I look at the files they seem to be corrupted...like bits and pieces are scrapped together.